# JavaScript, namespace, IE11 error SCRIPT5009

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

This is the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myobject = new mynamespace.main.Main ("This is string.");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ant this is **test.js**:

```
var mynamespace =
{
    main:
    {
        controller: {},
        view: {}
    },

    elements: {}
};

mynamespace.main.Main = function (string)
{
    this.string = string;
    this.controller = new mynamespace.main.controller.Controller (this.string);
}

mynamespace.main.controller.Controller = function (string)
{
    this.view = new mynamespace.main.view.View (string);
    this.element = new mynamespace.elements.Element (string);
    console.log ("Controller, string: " + string);
}

mynamespace.main.view.View = function (string)
{
    console.log ("View, string: " + string);
}

mynamespace.elements.Element = function (string)
{
    console.log ("Element, string: " + string);
}
```

Both files are placed in the same folder.

Internet Explorer 11 return error: **SCRIPT5009: Object mynamespace is not defined.**

This code work only if I placed the code of **test.js** into HTML page. How can I fixed it please?

I don't use any library like jQuery.

Comment: you probably need a closing `</head>` tag

Comment: Lee: Sorry, I forgot to write it here. Still not working.

Comment: Is test.js in the same folder as where your page is being accessed? Have you checked that you can access test.js without issue?

Comment: @JLRishe: Yes, test.js is in the same folder and I can access it in browser.

Comment: I tested your code in IE11 and it works just fine.

Comment: @RomanD.Boiko: I have version 11.0.9600.17105 and tested on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I checked on two Win 8.1 machines with IE 11.0.9600.16661 and 11.0.9600.17105 (same as yours). Could it be that you have a typo in your code but not here on SO?

Comment: @RomanD.Boiko: Thank you very much for testing. I copy from here back to local files and still have the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue and in my case it was because of some comment tags in the js file. It didn't like these types of tags  <%= %>

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clear your cache?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ba430f1d-f3a5-44f0-aaec-3b09c4d68d1c/ie-11-javascript-files-are-not-loaded-correctly-from-cache?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Perhaps IE 11 syncronous script loading is not working as expected. I.e. its defaulting to async instead of in-place or deferred.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673524(v=vs.85).aspx

Otherwise, I cannot reproduce this with an identical setup in IE 11 on Win 64 win 7.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I replace `var myobject = new mynamespace.main.Main ("This is string.");` in HTML file by your code, but I still get the same error. It is strange.

Comment: Does it work if you wrap in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {`?

Comment: I don't think this could be the issue. He's not trying to access a DOM element that doesn't exist yet - he's trying to access a declared script object, and that script comes earlier in the document than his inline code that fails.

Comment: @FlavorScape: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue using your exact code in IE 11. I thought sometimes local files can defer to async and vice versa (with older browsers) but this is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you very much for testing. I tried clear the cache in IE and by CCleaner. I move to another folder, but still nothing. This is strange, after first open this file in IE is console empty, after reload I get error.

Comment: Try setting your security settings to default or low. Loading local files causes strange behavior in some environments. Does your network console show the file loading?

Comment: Do you think the netwoork tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx)? Edit: Yes, there are html and js file.